# Position an input text relative to the position of a table's second column

Tags: javascript

I have a table with 2 columns. I want to position an input text so that it looks like its in the second column of the table, but actually is not. How could I do this? In other words how can I get the correct x coordinate and where should I apply it (relative left?, margin? border? some other place?)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you use `rowspan="2"` to join these two columns into one?

Comment: There will be other content between the table and the input text. This other content has bigger width than the table so I can't put it in the table

Comment: You should supply more details then.

Comment: You can do it with absolute positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/6ee3x/. Your comment about "other content" doesn't really make sense to me - you asked how to position an input, so what does other content matter?

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the correct X coordinate? The table is not fixed length. I tried getting the x by 1.)the offsetWidth of the first cell and by 2.)getting the recursive offsetLeft of a input text from the second column of the table. Both solutions give values that are off by a few pixels.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand why you can't just put the input in the table cell in question - you can still make it absolutely positioned to put it over the top of any other cell content.

Comment: Here is the problem more detailed: I have a table with 2 columns. This table has no width attribute. Below the table comes a div that has width 100% (this div is actually a line). Since the div has width 100%, I can't put it in the table. Below this div I want to put an input text that has the same X coordinate as the rest of the elements in the table's second column.